# Edge Bevel Weight tool seems to have permanent effect

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Is there a way to remove the effects of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> Edge Bevel Weight tool? I can't find the option or hotkey for this.

Comment: in the N panel > Item > Edge Data > Bevel Weight?

Comment: Just set it to 0, and the thin blue line will disappear :)